# How to get all courses on moodle?

Tags: moodle

I need to show all moodle courses in menu listing.
Can anyone suggest me that how can I get all courses using php code or moodle inbuilt functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you are writing code to be run within Moodle, you can use the `get_courses()` function defined within `lib/datalib.php`. For example:

```
<?php
require_once(PATH_TO_MOODLE_ROOT . '/config.php');
$courses = get_courses();
print_r($courses);
```

will print out a data-dump of the returned array, showing details of all the courses in your Moodle site. This example is obviously not appropriate to use on a production site!

If you check the function definition in `lib/datalib.php` you will see the options available for restricting the result set to particular fields or controlling the sort order.

Comment: This script must start with the line `define('CLI_SCRIPT', true);` in order to be run.

Answer (score 3):

Include this file

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/lib/coursecatlib.php');
```

Use this function to get all courses in menu listing.

```
$allcourses = coursecat::get(0)->get_courses(array('recursive' => true));

var_dump($allcourses);exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show only enrolled course to student you can use following method.

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/blocks/course_overview/locallib.php');
global $USER,$DB;
$courses = enrol_get_users_courses($USER->id, true);
```

OR 
If you want list all courses..

```
global $DB;
$query = "SELECT id, fullname, shortname from {course}";
$courselist = $DB->get_records_sql($query);
foreach ($courselist as $course) {
    echo $course->fullname;
}
```

Thanks